# Клиент безперерывно слушает сервер

Tags: java

Как в Java сделать так, что клиентское приложение подключается к серверу и безперерывно слушает сообoщения от него. То есть вместо того, что клиент один раз подключился к серверу, услышал одну команду и сразу отключился, я хотел бы реализовать подключение клиента к серверу, клиент слушает без остановки данный порт и выводит данные в консоль.

#### Update 1

Доступ к серверу я не имею. Я выступаю в роли клиента. Надо подключение с помощью TCP

Подскажите куда копать надо.

Answer (score 2):

WebSocket вам в помощь. На Java проще паренной репы

Comment: А можете добавить хотя  бы пример или ссылку на ресурс?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/websocket

Comment: Это Javascript) Но идею понял

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-websockets вот либа - https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket

Comment: А если не при помощи WebSocket? Через протокол HTTP?

Comment: SSE (Server-Sent Events)? HTTP не умеет так

Comment: Без помощи WebSocket можно только реализовать сам WebSocket. Протокол HTTP говорит лишь о том, в какой порт нужно стучаться (80).